# Missing select keyword from exported Oracle View DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm having difficulties exporting / and importing my database using impdm, and expdp.

I have a valid schema, with a couple of working views that were created using statements similar to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW someView (column1, column2, etc) AS SELECT column1, column2, etc FROM someTable;
```

I can query the views no problem, and I get valid results:

```
SELECT * FROM someView;
```

However if I try to export the DDL for the views, using expdp, or even do a simple dbms_metadata.get_ddl query. i.e.:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','someView','someSchema') FROM DUAL
```

... then some of the view ddls will be missing the SELECT keyword. So instead of getting back the original DDL that was used to create the view in the first place, I get something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW someView (column1, column3, etc) AS column1, column2, etcfrom someTable;
```

This is preventing me from doing image export / imports as on the import step things will blow up on:

> ORA-39083: Object type VIEW failed to create with error: 
>   ORA-00928:missing SELECT keyword

Suggestions?

I'm using Oracle 11.2 on Windows.

Comment: This looks like bug 12886950, which doesn't seem to have been fixed (or even reproduced). I think you need to raise a service request with Oracle.

Comment: @AlexPoole - where can I find more information about this bug? Google doesn't seem to bring up any results. Ughh.. nevermind looks like I need to register @ https://support.oracle.com

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work around that might work for you, if you want to export the view script (select statement ONLY) you can access the view code from the system table `USER_VIEWS` (assuming you have access to it. The script for the view is under column `TEXT` here is a sample query

```
Select view_name,text
From user_views
```

After you get the select statement you do some simple string manupilation and append the `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` syntax

I find these system tables very useful

Comment: Any suggestions on workarounds for expdp ? Ultimately that's the way I'd want to do the export.

Comment: @vicjugador - if it is the bug I mentioned, the only workaround seems to be to use `exp`/`imp` instead, which isn't ideal. Extracting the views manually like this might be a better option.

Comment: @vicjugador what exactly are you trying to do (copy to another schema, backup..etc?)

Comment: @JafarKofahi I'm trying to update our database snapshot for development purposes using our preexisting build framework that uses impdm, and expdp. Unfortunately, it stopped working once some new views were added.

Comment: @AlexPoole So this bug doesn't exist with exp/imp? I've always used impdm/expdp,  why do you say that exp/imp isn't ideal?

Comment: @vicjugador - I only have the brief bug notes (on suportoracle.com, yes) to go on. It might not be that but it looks very similar, and it looks pretty rare. exp/imp isn't ideal because it's deprecated and much less flexible. I would think it would be better to use expdp for everything you can, and deal with the views separately (or from source control).